# C Casting between different struct-pointers during "simulated inheritance"

Tags: c, inheritance, casting, struct, free

Hey I'm currently porting a C++ program into C and I simplified I'm using the following code when I'm simulating inheritence from C++ classes using structs in C.

```
typedef struct GenTask GenTask;
typedef struct Task Task;
typedef struct UserTask UserTask;

struct GenTask{
  char name[MAXCHAR];
  boolean isUserTask;
  int k;
  void (*print)(Task*);
};

GenTask* newGenTask(const char* n){
  GenTask* inhTask = (GenTask*)malloc(sizeof(GenTask));
  strncpy(inhTask->name, n, MAXCHAR);
  inhTask->k = 1;
  return inhTask;
}

struct Task{
  GenTask* inhTask;
};

void printTask(Task* task){
  printf("\nThis is Task: %s",task->inhTask->name);
}

Task* newTask(const char* n){
  Task* task = (Task*)malloc(sizeof(Task));
  task->inhTask = newGenTask(n);
  task->inhTask->isUserTask = false;
  task->inhTask->print = printTask;
  return task;
}

void deleteTask(Task* task){
  free(task->inhTask);
  free(task);
}

struct UserTask{
  GenTask* inhTask;
  int m;
};

void printUserTask(Task* task){
  UserTask* ut = (UserTask*)task;
  printf("\nThis is UserTask nbr: %d",ut->m);
}

UserTask* newUserTask(const char* n){
  UserTask *ut = (UserTask*)malloc(sizeof(UserTask));
  ut->inhTask = newGenTask(n);
  ut->inhTask->isUserTask = true;
  ut->inhTask->print = printUserTask;
  ut->m=100;
  return ut;
}

void deleteUserTask(UserTask* utask){
  free(utask->inhTask);
  free(utask);
}
```

I've tried running the code and it works as expected (or rather as I wish for it to work;)). My question though, is if there is any risk that the extra "UserTask-memory" is exposed after type casting like below.

```
Task* task = (Task*)newUserTask("A UserTask");
```

There seems to be no problem when I cast back into a UserTask pointer.

```
UserTask* utask = (UserTask*)task;
```

I assume that when I free the memory for "A UserTask", I suffies to free utask and using deleteUserTask(utask)? If I instead free task using deleteTask(task), I guess the UserTask specific memory won't get freed.

I my all new to both C++ and C, been using Java before and the dynamic memory allocation is still a bit scary... Thanks for any help!

/Patrik

Answer (score 2):

I think the 'normal' way to do this in C is to include the parent struct inline not as a pointer, i.e.:

```
struct Task{
  GenTask inhTask; 
};
```

That way a pointer to a task struct can be up cast to a Task*. And of course the 'parent' is freed automatically along with the child instance.

Comment: Yes I've seen that as well. The reason I didn't do that is that the GenTask-struct contains pointers as well (in the implemenation) and I have to get down into it to free that memory anyhow. But yeah I still see how it is a bit redudant to have it as a pointer. Might change that. But what do you explicitly mean by "task" in "That way a pointer to a task struct can be up cast to a Task*". Any struct that has a GenTask? Thanks for the reply

Comment: I mean, if you have a Task* you can treat it as a GenTask* transparently, instead of having to explicitly dereference. If GenTask* has pointers to memory that must be freed when the struct is deleted, then you have to do that for all the 'sub-structs' as well.